# What's the syntax to remove a baseline in ClearCase?

Tags: clearcase, cleartool, clearcase-ucm

It looks like I can remove a just created baseline from ClearCase UCM with a simple command:

```
$ cleartool rmbl p_xxx_main_2_0_3_1
```

but this gives me the error:

```
cleartool: Error: Unable to find baseline "p_xxx_main_2_0_3_1".
cleartool: Error: Unable to remove baseline "p_xxx_main_2_0_3_1".
```

I can list the baselines:

```
$ cleartool lsbl -s
p_xxx_main_2_0_3_1.1465
p_xxx_main_2_0_3_1
```

I'm running this operations in the stream snapshot view. It looks like I need to specify more info. How should I specify the baseline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should at least specify the pvob (UCM Project Vob where the baseline is defined):

```
cleartool rmbl p_xxx_main_2_0_3_1@/vobs/apvob
```

If you don't know the pvob of the baseline, it is the same than the one of the Stream where your UCM view is currently attached to.
And you can get the Stream of your view by typing (anywhere within said view):

```
cleartool lsstream -cview
```

Comment: I've just discovered it using trial and error. It worked with just the vob: cleartool rmbl p_xxx_main_2_0_3_1@\MyVob